# url rewrite in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

hey guys,
i am using IIS7 and urlrewrite, what i am trying to do is instead of writing the rule for all the url, i have created common rule and redirect pointed to home.aspx, and i have stored the rawurl and its destination url in the database and in global.asax i checking if the rawurl exists in the database if it is, then i am redirecting it to its found destination url, but its not working, when i click on any link it goes to homepage only.
here is my web.config urlrewrite code:

```
<rewrite>  
    <rules>  
        <rule name="index">  
            <match url="^(\W*)" />  
            <action type="Rewrite" url="home.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />  
        </rule>  
    </rules>  
</rewrite>
```

and below is my global.asax code.

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SiteSqlServer").ConnectionString)  
Dim adapGetVanity As New SqlDataAdapter("select originalurl from  crossarticle_vanityurl where url = '"+str.Remove(0,1)+"'", connection)  
Dim dtGetVanity As New DataTable  
adapGetVanity.Fill(dtGetVanity)  

If dtGetVanity.Rows.Count <> 0 Then  
    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(dtGetVanity.Rows(0)  (0).ToString())  
End If
```

Please help me for this, or suggest any possible things, i want to get rid or this, as in my application there could be any type of url, so i cannot be specific for this... if this is not the correct way, please give some suggestion